# relative path to uri

Tags: c#, url, path, uri

I have a Uri object - what property of it will give me the relative path? Of how can I decipher the relative path the file with this Uri. I am coding in c#.

Comment: are you working with asp.net? relative to the current page?

Comment: yes aps.net and relative to current path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the [Uri.MakeRelativeUri Method (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri.aspx)

straight from MSDN:

```
// Create a base Uri.
Uri address1 = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/");

// Create a new Uri from a string.
Uri address2 = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/index.htm?date=today"); 

// Determine the relative Uri.  
Console.WriteLine("The difference is {0}", address1.MakeRelativeUri(address2));
```

---

furthermore, if you are always looking for the relative path from the root of the domain you could also use `myUri.AbsolutePath`

Here's a screenie of the Uri debug view with two examples of `MakeRelativeUri` at the bottom using the following Uri objects

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri.aspx#Y600");
Uri myHost = new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com/");
Uri myHost2 = new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/");
```

[image: Uri debug]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a relative path to the Uri like below.

```
var Url = new Uri("/something/test", UriKind.Relative);
```